# Matlab and python pwelch methods are producing slightly different results

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to exactly reproduce matlab results in python....

Matlab code:
[psd_x, f] = pwelch(x,window=256,noverlap=0,f=1024,fs=fs_value)

Python code:
f, psd_x = signal.welch(x, window='hamming', fs=fs_value, nfft=1024, noverlap=0, return_onesided=False, nperseg=256, detrend=False)

These welch methods return slightly different results. Visually the look basically the same, but they are off by a few decimals. Does anyone know how to get an exact replication?

Using return_onesided=True actually makes the outcomes quite close but they are slightly different still.

Matlab first 5 values:
0.001541819790656
0.002796051763211
0.002075072237846
0.001242789331872
0.000586016815412
Python first 5 values:
array([0.00154778, 0.00280573, 0.00207962, 0.0012426 , 0.00058375])

The difference may seem trivial but the mean is a bit different matlab = 2.257662957584677e-05, python = 2.2605062684523284e-05 and it impacts my downstream results.